# Probability that a majority approves

Tags: probability

Im having a really hard time solving this probability problem

Ques: The odds that a Ph.D. thesis will be favorably reviewed by three indepent examiners are 5 to 2, 4 to 3 and 3 to 4. What is the probability that a majority approve the thesis?

Ans: $209/343$

I tried this approach:
I calculated the probability that 3 of them will approve and added the probability that 2 of them approve since 2/3 is also a majority but the answer I get is greater than 1which is totally wrong Im out of ideas here

$$P= \frac{5}{7}\frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{7} + \frac{5}{7}\frac{4}{7} + \frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{7} + \frac{5}{7}\frac{3}{7}=\frac{389}{343}$$

PS. Sorry for the format im new in math stackexchange and desperate to answer the problem. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You are missing some terms.  Your first term is in reference to the all three examiners approve.  The second term as you have written it is in reference to the first two examiners approving **and the third either approving or disapproving**.  We already accounted for the situation where all three approve in the first term, but you accidentally counted it again here.  Fix this by making the second term where the first two approve and the third disapproves.  Similarly fix the remaining two terms.

Comment: Now that you have the answer don't forget to edit your question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @JMoravitz ohhh now i get it! thank you so much for the explanation

Comment: @anderstood will do, thank you for referencing it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{5}{7} \frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{7}+\frac{5}{7} \frac{4}{7} \color{red}{\frac{4}{7}}+\frac{5}{7} \color{red}{\frac{3}{7}}\frac{3}{7}+\color{red}{\frac{2}{7}} \frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{7} =\color{blue}{\frac{209}{343}} .
\end{eqnarray*}